# How can I iterate through two file lists at the same time

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to generate a bunch of (multi)plots from data in two different directories, call them dirA, and dirB.  I'm using multiplot, and I'd like each one to look something like this (forgive my artistry)...

[image]

where plot A is generated from a data file in dirA and plot B is from dirB.

I've tried this (simplified a bit)...

```
filesA = system("ls dirA/*.dat")
filesB = system("ls dirB/*.dat")

i=0
do for [fn in filesA]{
    set output 'anappropriatefilename.png'

    set multiplot layout 1,2 rowsfirst

    set size 0.25,1.0
    plot fn using 1:2 with lines

    set multiplot layout 1,2 rowsfirst
    set size 0.75,1.0
    plot filesB[i] 1:2 with lines

    i=i+1

    unset multiplot
}
```

but this gives me a

> ':' expected

error on the line

```
plot filesB[i] 1:2 with lines
```

So maybe I just don't know how to correctly reference the filesB array with an index?

Or maybe there's a better way to do this?

I hope I explained my problem well, any suggestions are welcome

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have files `A1,A2,...An` and `B1,B2,...Bm`. Is `m` always equal to `n`? What should the output file(s) be named `C1,C2,...Cn`?

The following example works under windows. Hopefully, you can adapt it for Linux.

**Code:**

```
### create multiplots from different filelists (Windows)
reset session
unset multiplot

myDirA = 'dirA\'
myDirB = 'dirB\'
myType = '*.dat'
filesA = system('dir /b '.myDirA.myType)  # Windows
filesB = system('dir /b '.myDirB.myType)  # Windows
# spaces in path or filenames probably will create problems and would require a workaround

set terminal pngcairo size 800,200 font ",8"
# Assumption: number of filesA and number of filesB are identical
#             and no spaces in path or filename
do for [i=1:words(filesA)] {
    set output sprintf("myPlot%03d.png",i)

    set multiplot layout 1,2
    set origin 0,0
    set size 0.25, 1.0
    plot myDirA.word(filesA,i) u 1:2 w lines

    set origin 0.25, 0
    set size 0.75, 1.0
    plot myDirB.word(filesB,i) u 1:2 w lines

    unset multiplot
    set output
}
### end of code
```

Comment: Thanks!  This worked great.  I guess I didn't realize that the system call returns a single string that could be parsed with the word function .  Cheers